# Question about characteristic of field

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to prove that finite field cannot be of characteristic zero?

I think, we should use result that finite field is isomorphic to $Z/pZ$.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $A$ is a ring with $1$ (in particular a field), there is a unique ring homomorphism $\varphi\colon \mathbb{Z}\to A$; the kernel of $\varphi$ is $n\mathbb{Z}$, where $n$ is the characteristic of $A$; what does it mean that $\ker\varphi=0\mathbb{Z}=\{0\}$?

Answer (score 0):

For any ring $R$ there is a unique ring homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb Z\rightarrow R$ and the characteristic of a ring is the nonnegative generator of its kernel. If this characteristic is $0$ then the ring homomorphism is an injection and $\mathbb Z$ and its image $\phi(\mathbb Z)\subseteq R$ are isomorphic. This implies that $R$ must be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

If $K$ is a field with characteristic zero, then  for all $n\in \Bbb Z^*$,  $n.1_K\neq 0$, hence the map $\Bbb Z\to K$; $n\mapsto n.1_K$ is injective, and $K$ is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

A less technical idea: apply the pigeonhole principle to the set of sums
$$1$$
$$1+1$$
$$1+1+1$$
$$\cdots$$
$$1+\cdots+1\qquad\text{(1+cardinal of field) times}$$